# Form won't submit when generated with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm generating a login form in javascript. The form displays perfectly and the HTML looks fine in Google Dev Tools but the form won't submit when I click the submit button.

Heres's the generated form code:

```
var loginBox = '<div id="loginBox">';
loginBox    += '<h1>Login</h1>';
loginBox    += 'Please use the form to login below<br /><br />';
loginBox    += '<form action="home.php" method="post">';
loginBox    += '<div class="input">';
loginBox    += '<label for="username">Username</label>';
loginBox    += '<input type="text" name="username" />';
loginBox    += '</div>';
loginBox    += '<div class="input">';
loginBox    += '<label for="userpass">Password</label>';
loginBox    += '<input type="password" name="password" />';
loginBox    += '</div>';
loginBox    += '<div class="clear"></div>';
loginBox    += '<div class="input">';
loginBox    += '<input type="submit" class="submit button" value="Submit" />';
loginBox    += '</div>';
loginBox    += '</form>';
loginBox    += '</div>';
```

Any ideas on why this wouldn't work?
I know I could probably write some Javascript to submit the form when the submit button is pressed but I don't see why that should be necessary.
Thanks

Comment: Try giving the submit button a name

Comment: Nope, still not working.

Comment: Try giving the form a name, changing the submit button inPut type to be a button, and then have a onclick event of the button submit the form based off of form name.

Comment: Check the resultant html with either Firebug of Chrome's inspector to make sure your tags are being closed properly. It's entirely possible that your button is being thrown outside the form.

Comment: I tried adding the generated Javascript straight into the HTML with a display:none; but it still doesn't work.
Interestingly though if I remove the display:none; it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added it to this page and it seemed to work. Do you have any client validation scripts that might intercept the form submit event?

My code:

```
$(loginBox).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Damn I know what I did. I have this code to hide the login box:
$('#loginWrapper').fadeIn();
$('#loginBox').bind('click', function(){
   return false;
});

$('#loginWrapper').bind('click', function() {
   killLogin(); 
});
loginBoxShown = true;

Any idea how I can do this without affecting the submit button?

Comment: It removes the login box when clicked outside

Comment: Does the #loginWrapper act as an overlay around the #loginBox? In that case I would just use the code: $('#loginWrapper').bind('click', function() { $("#loginWrapper, #loginBox").fadeOut(); });

Answer (score 3):

The bigger question is why are you creating a login box with Javascript?

I think that it is cleaner to refactor it and have the form live inside a hidden div, and use JavaScript to show/hide it as required. This would get around some brower's issues with dynamically adding a form using element.innerHTML.

If that is not an option then you may have to change your JS to add it using the DOM. This is quite verbose and not very easy to read.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right. It's probably best just to put it in a hidden div.

Comment: It didn't work.
When I removed the display:none; from the HTML it worked.
Could it be something to do with the display:none;?